# Login credentials for password reset not working in Laravel 7

Tags: authentication, swiftmailer, laravel-7

I tested my credentials with `https://www.smtper.net/` and they work flawlessly for port 25 (without encryption) and port 465 (with encryption). Maybe there is an error in my Laravel config files:

.env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=###.netcup.net
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=me@mydomain.de
MAIL_PASSWORD=#########
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=me@mydomain.de
MAIL_FROM_NAME="me"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I also tried

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=###.netcup.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=me@mydomain.de
MAIL_PASSWORD=#########
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=me@mydomain.de
MAIL_FROM_NAME="me"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

config/mail.php:

```
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '###.netcup.net'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'null'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),   
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'me@mydomain.de'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'me'),
    ],
```

Both port 25 and 465 requests bring this error in Laravel:

```
[2020-05-11 12:56:35] local.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "me@mydomain.de" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
". {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"me@mydomain.de\" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
\". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
\". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
\". at C:\\wamp64\\www\\vanilli\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\Esmtp\\AuthHandler.php:191)
```

This issue occured several times here but none of the answers did work. This happens in a vanilla installation of Laravel 7, nothing has been modified except these config files. Anyone has an idea? Thanks.

Comment: does `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` also fail?

Comment: Yes, I also tried TLS on port 587 and it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your email address

[Less Secure](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

I think you mean "Allow less secure apps."